# Как равномерно растянуть в gridlayout содержимое

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml

Привет! Возникла необходимость в полном заполнении gridlayout'a цифрами, чтобы полностью задействовать место(увеличить кнопки) и не было свободного пространства. Возможно ли это каким-нибудь образом сделать, использую именно gridlayout? Т.е хочу создать цифры наподобие калькулятора. Атрибут android:useDefaultMargins="true" только немного растянул цифры. Надеюсь внятно объяснил :)

Вот код выделенного элемента:

```
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="4"
        android:useDefaultMargins="true">

        <Button android:text="1"/>
        <Button android:text="2"/>
        <Button android:text="3"/>
        <Button android:text="4"/>
        <Button android:text="5"/>
        <Button android:text="6"/>
        <Button android:text="7"/>
        <Button android:text="8"/>
        <Button android:text="9"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:text="0" />
        <Button android:text="x"/>

    </GridLayout>
```

[image: проблемный Gridlayout]

Answer (score 1):

[image: скриншот]

GridLayout has the column and row weights which can be used like below to evenly create each grid item in the gridlayout like the image above.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
grid:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
grid:columnCount="4">
<Button android:layout_width="0dp"
    style="?buttonStyle"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="-1"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
    grid:layout_gravity="fill"/>
```

Comment: Здесь stackoverflow на **русском**.

Comment: Мне нужно растянуть именно те элементы, которые приведены выше. Ни больше ни меньше

Comment: мой код не работает?

Comment: Я уже видел этот ответ на англоязычном stackoverflow. Мало того, что он заработает только тогда, когда подключаться  сл. зависимости: 
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1', которые вы не указали, но даже при этом он мне не подходит. И я не говорил, что он не работает - он мне не подходит.

Comment: даже боюсь спрашивать почему он вам не подходит

Comment: А я не боюсь спросить: почему не подходит? Концепция "весов" появилась в API21, а это значит вам придётся либо повысит ваш минимальный уровень API до 21 (Android 5.0) либо воспользоваться библиотекой поддержки. Вы кстати под какой уровень API разрабатываете?